# PdfBox - change font or fontName in pdf file?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

please tell me.

I have a pdf files with fonts HPDFAA+Arial-BoldMTBold. This font name incorrect and it's a subset...
I change fonts with library Asponse.pdf.dll, https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/net/replace-text-in-pdf/, paragraph - Replace fonts in existing PDF file, but this library trail version.

How can i do this with PDFBox? I want to replace this font on Arial-BoldMT or rename font name.

UPD: my attempts have led nowhere...In PDFontDescriptor i can rename font, but how i can apply for PDFont? Or i'm going the wrong way?

```
        PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("Sample.pdf"));

        PDPageTree pages = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
        for (PDPage page : pages) {
            PDResources res = page.getResources();

            for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames()) {
                PDFont font = res.getFont(fontName);
                PDFontDescriptor fontDescriptor = font.getFontDescriptor();
                System.out.println("fontDes: " + fontDescriptor.getFontName());
                String oldFontName = fontDescriptor.getFontName();
                String newFontName = oldFontName.replace("Arial-BoldMTBold", "Arial-BoldMT");
                fontDescriptor.setFontName(newFontName);

                System.out.println("font: " + font.getName());
            }
```

Comment: What do you want to change the name into? "HPDFAA+" is correct, this is used for subsets. Or do you want to remove the ending "Bold"? Can you share the PDF?

Comment: Yes, a want to remove the ending "Bold", because this font name incorrectly recognized in Adobe Illustrator, not found font. But if replace font and font name "Arial-BoldMT", it work correct. PDF files are unloaded from the program that gives the incorrect font name.
Sample file: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/cAO8p1IZFEKMdQ

Comment: The reason that it didn't work is because the font name is at 3 different places  (You can see that with PDFDebugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that is tailored to your file. It will only help you if this is about many similar files.

```
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(XXX,"outerBox.pdf")))
{
    PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
    for (COSName name : page.getResources().getFontNames())
    {
        PDFont font = page.getResources().getFont(name);
        String fontName = font.getName();
        if (font instanceof PDType0Font && fontName.endsWith("BoldMTBold"))
        {
            PDType0Font type0font = (PDType0Font) font;
            String newFontName = fontName.substring(0, fontName.length() - 4);
            type0font.getCOSObject().setString(COSName.BASE_FONT, newFontName);
            PDCIDFont descendantFont = type0font.getDescendantFont();
            descendantFont.getCOSObject().setString(COSName.BASE_FONT, newFontName);
            PDFontDescriptor fontDescriptor = descendantFont.getFontDescriptor();
            fontDescriptor.setFontName(newFontName);
        }
    }
    doc.save(new File(XXX,"outerBox-saved.pdf"));
}
```

PDF structure, seen with PDFDebugger:

[image]

Comment: It's `Loader.loadPDF` for the development head towards PDFBox 3, existing PDFBox 2 releases still use `PDDocument.load`, see also https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's work. In PDFDebugger looked quickly, so i didn't notice these places...